# Move email to a search folder after being categorized

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automate my outlook a bit for work. I am trying to write a macro that can move an email to a custom search folder after being categorized manually. I'm fairly new to writing macros so I am not sure if this is 100% correct but I gave it my best shot. I am getting a compile error here and am not sure what could be causing it.

```
Sub MoveFollowUpEmails()

    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objCategory As Outlook.Category
    Dim objSearchFolder As Outlook.SearchFolder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set objInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objCategory = Application.Session.Categories("[01] Follow up")
    
    ' Check if the search folder already exists, create it if not
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSearchFolder = objInbox.Parent.Folders("[01] Follow up")
    If objSearchFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set objSearchFolder = objInbox.Parent.Folders.Add("[01] Follow up", olSearchFolder)
        objSearchFolder.Save
    End If
    
    For Each objMail In objInbox.Items
        If objMail.Categories = "[01] Follow up" Then
            objMail.Move objSearchFolder
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objSearchFolder = Nothing
    Set objCategory = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "I am getting a compile error" - what is the error, and on which line?  FYI you should can cel that `On Error Resume Next` as soon as it's no longer needed, otherwise you may miss other problems in your code.

Comment: Where did you find `Outlook.SearchFolder` (that doesn't seem to be an existing object type in outlook) ?  Likewise `olSearchFolder` is not a recognized constant.

Comment: An Outlook search folder is a virtual folder - like a saved search which you run every time you access the folder.  It doesn't actually contain mail items itself.  Are you just trying to create a regular folder and move items to it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as others have noted, `olSearchFolder` is not defined in OOM, and the only way to create a search folder is to call `Search.Save`, you cannot use `Folders.Add` for that. And you probably don't want to - you just need a regular folder:

```
Set objSearchFolder = objInbox.Parent.Folders.Add("[01] Follow up")
```

Secondly, your code is trying to move matching items in the Inbox folder, and that will fail since you are modifying the collection (by calling `MailItem.Move`) that you are enumerating. Don't loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` and loop backwards. Off the top of my head:

```
set items = objInbox.Items.Restrict("[Categories]='[01] Follow up'")
for i = items.Count to 1 step -1
  set objMail = items(i)
  objMail.Move objSearchFolder
next
```